# Should a Notification Center have an infinite history or should it allow the user to close them?

Tags: web-app, notification, history

I'm working on a Notification Center (in a web application) and I can't find any information about the notifications history.

So I don't know what is the best behaviour to apply for my notification center.

Example: Facebook and Pinterest have an infinite history.

- Should I keep all the notifications in history, in which context?
- Should I allow the user to close the notifications, in which context?

For more context, I'm working on a Financial Application for Advisors.
So there is no "Messages notifications", the notifications we'll find in the Notification Center will be more like "There are new alternatives available in your comparison #1". The notification will redirect the user to the source.

Here's my sources for the notifications:

- https://uxdesign.cc/notification-center-7ec3d41efb10
- https://medium.muz.li/designing-notifications-for-applications-3cad56fecf96
- https://uxdesign.cc/different-types-of-notifications-websites-apps-and-beyond-f5dc1ba42509

Comment: This will depend on your users' need Leane. If the history of last 7 days is all they need, there will no need to display all notifications. If needed the notifications may be put in a separate page with the added option to 'View entire history' and preferably to clear them as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping all of it and try to categorize it if possible. (i.e. notification from the system, message from other users, alerts etc.). Yet again, you have to discuss this with your users.